# React: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I'm inside my `render()`-method creating some `<select>`. I want to select a default value but only when it's not a `<select multiple>`. I tried this but encountered the error in the title. How would I code this correctly?

```
<select key={setting.id} multiple={setting.multiple} {setting.multiple ? '' : 'value={setting.default || ""}'}><select>
                                                      ^ error occurs here
```

---

**EDIT:**

It is important that the select has no value-attribute at all in the case it is a `<select multiple>` to mitigate the `The value prop supplied to <select> must be an array if multiple is true.`-warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSX, the `{}` do not output strings as is the case in many templating languages, you need to look at it as an assignment where the left hand is the property, e.g. `multiple=`, and the right hand is a JavaScript expression that returns a value to be assigned, e.g. `{ setting.multiple }` - it gets evaluated and assigned to the `multiple` property.

Now to set the value depending on the `setting` prop just follow the same logic:

```
<select value={ setting.multiple ? [] : (setting.default || "") } />
```

EDIT: to explain why the error says `expected "..."`. If the `{}` do not fall on the right side of an assignment it is expected that you want to spread multiple properties, for example
`const props = { value: "foo", name: "myInput" }; <select {...props } />`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to have no value-attribute at all if it's a multi-select

Comment: @MiXT4PE I don't know why this would make a difference, but React will just render `<select>` if the `value` property is `""`.

Comment: It will throw a warning: `The value prop supplied to <select> must be an array if multiple is true.` which I would like to mitigate

Comment: @MiXT4PE then pass `[]`, same result, no `value` attribute in the generated DOM.

Comment: Edited the ternary to match the logic you were going after.

Comment: Hmm not exactly what I was initially looking for but a solid working approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Something like below may solve your problem:

```
render(){
      let selValue = "";
      if(setting.multiple)
        val = setting.default;
      return(
        <select key={setting.id} multiple={setting.multiple} value={selValue}><select>
      )
    }
```

**EDIT:**
According to your needs you can also use below code:

```
let select = (<select key={setting.id} multiple={setting.multiple} value={setting.default}><select>)
if(setting.multiple)
  select = (<select key={setting.id} multiple={setting.multiple}><select>)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to have no value-attribute at all if it's a multi-select

Comment: If I understand correctly you don't want value field in select if you have setting.multiple? If so I have edited my answer it will meet your requirement

Comment: That is about the same as @Nayanshahs solution but I would like to avoid the duplicate code. Thanks for your time tho - have a upvote.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it this way?

```
setting.multiple
? <select key={setting.id} multiple={setting.multiple}></select>
: <select key={setting.id} multiple={setting.multiple} value={setting.default || ""}</select>
```

Comment: That would be a possibility. Is there a way of mitigating the duplicate code?